# Python automatically converts number to date

Tags: python, date, type-conversion

I am dropping some numerical values in a column using the following code, but then it somehow changes **all** the numerical values to **date** type, which is not what I need. I cannot see how to fix it, so I would really appreciate if some of you could help fix this error for me.

```
df = pd.read_csv(datapath+"CompleteOrder_HANOI_Alltime.csv") 
df = df.drop(df[df.completed_orders == 0].index)
df = df.dropna(subset = ["completed_orders"])
df['y'] = np.log(df['completed_orders'])

df['y'] = df.drop(df[df.y <= 0].index)
df = df.drop('completed_orders', axis = 1)
df = df.drop('percent_completed', axis = 1)
df['ds'] = df['to_char']
df = df.drop('to_char', axis = 1)
df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
```

Comment: Could you provide an example file for "CompleteOrder_HANOI_Alltime.csv" that allows other to reproduce your error?

Comment: @EdgarH: I finally got it:) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your last statement converts df['ds'] to datetime.  Add a print statement of df['ds'] to see what's being converted.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It converts to datetime64[ns]. But I was able to fix it:)